# Find names with at least 2 vowels in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find names with 2 or more vowels in a table.

I was trying

`SELECT name FROM players WHERE name LIKE '%[aeiou]%[aeiou]%';`

But I have no results with this query, can someone please help me and show me where is my mistake?

Comment: LIKE doesn't support that syntax. You can use REGEXP for that - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a regular expression you can determine if a value has more than two vowels.

```
SELECT `name` FROM `players` WHERE `name` REGEXP '([aeiou].*){2}'
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94f17/1)

Comment: Excellent, SQL fiddle is excellent tool for online. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> You can do your job with help of **Regular Expressions**.
>   You may use like..

This query use to find any number of vowels letter.

```
SELECT name FROM players where lower(name)  REGEXP 'a|e|i|o|u';
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a51f/2)

OR

```
SELECT name FROM players where lower(name)  REGEXP '[aeiou]';
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a51f/3)

This query use to find more than two vowels letter.

```
SELECT name FROM players where lower(name)  REGEXP '([a|e|i|o|u].*){2}';
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a51f/3)

OR

```
SELECT name FROM players where lower(name)  REGEXP '([aeiou].*){2}';
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a51f/5)

[image]

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: You don't need to use `lower()` as it searches without case sensitivity by default unless you're searching binary strings. Also you don't need to use the `|` (logical OR) operator in a character class; again that's assumed.

Comment: Yes we can do without | (logical OR). Thanks for helping @BenSwinburne